# Monitoring Server Connections - Netstat formatting issue

Tags: awk, grep, watch, netstat, uniq

I have had a few issues with a server recently. 
So i just wanted to leave a window showing the unique and IP's of connected devices.

I have been using:

```
watch -n 5 "netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :80 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr"
```

This works okay, but i have a formatting issue i cannot resolve, It seems to be when local connections appear.

Example of the output (Screenshot)
[image: Aligment falls out]
Example of Netstat without pipe
[image: Results from NetStat]
The reason for the confusion, is i am using `awk '{print $5}'`
to print the 5th column only

I am assuming its because i am trying to use watch with pips and something does not agree with the other.

Can anyone suggest a tweak to the one liner, 
Or can anyone advise of another tool to monitor the active connections to the server (Not interested in local connections)

**Edited**
Here is what i am using now.
I decided against Watch due to the number of formatting issues.

```
RED='\033[00;31m'
RESTORE='\033[0m'
YELLOW='\033[00;33m'
PURPLE='\033[00;35m'
LCYAN='\033[01;36m'
BLUE='\033[00;34m'
LIGHTGRAY='\033[00;37m'

while true
do
echo -e ${RED}"Connection Script"
echo -e ${YELLOW}"Current Active Connections to the Server Port 80"
  netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:80 / {print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sed 's/:.*//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
echo -e ${RESTORE}
echo -e ${PURPLE}"FTP Connections: 21"
  netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:21 / {print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sed 's/:.*//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
echo -e ${RESTORE}
echo -e ${LCYAN}"SSH/'SFTP' Connections: 22"
  netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:22 / {print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sed 's/:.*//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
echo -e ${RESTORE}
echo -e ${RED}"Yellowfin Connections: 8181"
  netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:8181 / {print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sed 's/:.*//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
echo -e ${RESTORE}
MySQLCon=$(netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:3306 /' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | wc -l)
echo -e ${RESTORE}
echo -e $LIGHTGRAY"MySQL Active Connections on port 3306 =" $MySQLCon
echo -e ${RESTORE}
  sleep 5
  clear
done
```

I appreciate the feedback provided here, Its been a interesting learning curve 
Example of the outputted script:

[image]

Part of image has been blacked out as the IP is special ;-)

Comment: `grep | awk` and `awk | sed` are both anti-patterns. `awk` can do the jobs of all three easily enough that there's almost never a reason to pipe like that.

Comment: What is the formatting issue exactly? What is wrong with your example screenshot? What is there that shouldn't be? What isn't there that should be?

Comment: First screenshot shows external IP's But then i get all that TCP Connection below. 
I am still trying to get my head around the whole Lingo of linux and its syntax, But someone advise using just awk like yourself. 
Problem is i can never get it to work with Watch. 
`awk '$5 ~ /:80$/ { split($5,A,":") ; if ( !u[A[1]]++ ) print A[1] ;} `
or the full line i was using 
`watch -n 5 netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '$5 ~ /:80$/ { split($5,A,":") ; if ( !u[A[1]]++ ) print A[1] ;} '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going into this "odd" output.

Look at the command that `watch` claims it is running. Specifically look at the `awk` script. See that it is `awk '{print }'`?

That's because you embedded the entire command in double quotes so the shell itself expands `$5` as a positional parameter and it disappears before `awk` even runs and you end up printing out the entire line.

Drop the `sed` from the pipeline and you'll see that *every* line is the full line in the output. (Alternatively drop the `awk` from the pipeline and you'll see that the output doesn't change at all.)

The only reason some of the lines **aren't** full is because the `sed` is dropping everything before `::ffff:` on lines that contain that. Which, you'll notice, none of the IPv4 lines at the end do (which is why they show up in full). So the fact that you get even close to the output you expect is because you were *double covering* the "only print the remote IP column" goal.

This all is also why you get the status column in the output (despite not indicating that you want that in the first place).

Escape `\$` in the command to "fix" the pipeline.

That said going for "not using `grep` and `sed`" try this:

```
netstat -tn | awk '/:80 / {print $5}'
```

and see how close to what you want that gets you.

That will match `:80` in the wrong column so if you want to limit that to `Local Address` column you can do that by using `$4 ~ /:80$/` instead of just `/:80 /`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, This was educational. 
I now understand why using Quotes and Watch was not functioning properly. That being said, i have moved away from watch, and just created this in a Loop script every 5 seconds instead. 
This allows me to use Sed and AWK a little more without formatting issues> 
For example already i have split into 3 colums. 
HTTP 80 Connection, FTP 21 Connections, SSH 22 Connections. 
Showing a Unique with Count and Session time 
So going down this route has given me more control on the output.